# How to erase a line using the condition?

Tags: c++, stl

I've a string (*ifstream*) with next lines:

```
foo
foo+..
foo
```

And, I'd like know how to get the line where there is a symbol *+* and erase the remaining lines:

```
foo+..
```

to convert the stream into a string, I use:

```
string stream((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show the relevant part of your code so we understand how you're representing/holding onto your strings.

Comment: You got _one_ string with many lines separated by carriage return/new line. Correct?

Comment: Are you reading from console or from a text file? Are the strings in a single string that contain `'\n'` characters or multiple strings? What have you got so far?

Comment: Can the input be large ? The used algorithm might differ depending on the possibility to store the whole "file" in memory.

Comment: @nabulke, Luchian Grigore, I'm trying to erase the lines from _ifstream_

Comment: @ereOn, Yes, the file is very large (1000 lines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this alternative solution:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool HasNoPlus(const string &value)  
{ 
    return value.find('+') == string::npos; 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])   
{
    ifstream ifs("d:\\temp\\test.txt");

    vector<string> out;

    remove_copy_if(istream_iterator<string>(ifs), 
                   istream_iterator<string>(), 
                   back_inserter(out), 
                   HasNoPlus);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The test on `ifs` and the `close` call are both unnecessary. If the stream is in a bad state, nothing will be copied, and the stream will be closed anyway at the end of its scope.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the intermediate string, you can copy from `ifstream` directly to a new `ofstream`, using standard algorithms:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

struct has_no_plus {
    bool operator()(const std::string& str)
    {
        if (str.find('+') != std::string::npos)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");
    std::ofstream ofs("copy.txt");

    std::remove_copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ifs),
                        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ofs, "\n"),
                        has_no_plus());

    // or alternatively, in C++11:

    std::copy_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ifs),
                 std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                 std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ofs, "\n"),
                 [](const std::string& str)
                 {
                     return str.find('+') != str.npos;
                 });
}
```

Comment: Elements that satisfy the predicate are _not_ copied. I think you should inverse the logic?

Comment: @nabulke, You're right, I misread the Q and thought the lines with '+' are to be removed. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: You should rename your functor to avoid any confusion though.

Comment: Alright, now that it's all fixed, I'd like to ask the downvoter if the down vote still applies? :)

Answer (score 2):

```
int pos_plus = str.find('+');
int pos_beg = str.find_last_of('\n',pos_plus);
int pos_end = str.find_first_of('\n',pos_plus);
if(pos_beg == pos_plus) pos_beg = 0;
if(pos_end == pos_plus) pos_end = str.size();
str.erase(pos_beg,pos_end-pos_beg);
```

Comment: This is a C++ question, so use `string` methods instead of manually searching through the string and using `strcpy`. But the general idea is valid.

Comment: @Clement Bellot, Thanks, for the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

To filter input from ifstream (as mentioned in your comment), use a new ostringstream.
Read every line from ifstream (getline) and check whether it passes the filter condition.
If it passes, append it to the ostringstream.
When you take the string from the ostringstream, you will have the filtered string.

Comment: I already have a string using: _string stream((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());_ So there's no any sense to use _getline()_.